# Word Map Counter

Tags: java, dictionary, count, cpu-word

how do I instantiate a map, using the split(" ") on words, and iterate through the resulting array.
* Inside of the resulting for loop, you should insert a new key to the map every time you encounter a word that is not already a key in the map, and add to the word's count value every time you encounter a word that already exists in the map.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new Hash Map<String, Integer>();
    for (String s : string Array) {
        if (containerization(s)) {
            map.put(s, map.get(s) + 1);
        } else {
            map.put(s, 1);
        }
    }

  
    return map;

}
```

}

Comment: `Arrays.stream(str.split(" ")).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, Collectors.counting()))`

Comment: I am a new to coding. Do I use that instead of : Map<String, Integer> map = new Hash Map<String, Integer>();

Comment: You assign the result to a `Map<String, Long>`.

Answer (score 0):

The code you may want to write accoringly to the description:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "Hello world Hello all";
        Map<String, Integer> wordMap = countWords(input);
        System.out.println(wordMap); // {all=1, world=1, Hello=2}
    }

    private static HashMap<String, Integer> countWords(final String text) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> wordMap = new HashMap<>();
        String[] words = text.split(" "); // split the input string by space
        for (String word : words) {
            if (wordMap.containsKey(word)) {
                wordMap.put(word, wordMap.get(word) + 1); // increment count of existing word
            } else {
                wordMap.put(word, 1); // add new word to the map
            }
        }
        return wordMap;
    }
}
```

---

Note that it can be improved this way:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "Hello world Hello all";
        Map<String, Integer> wordMap = countWords(input);
        System.out.println(wordMap); // {all=1, world=1, Hello=2}
    }

    private static HashMap<String, Integer> countWords(final String text) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> wordMap = new HashMap<>();
        String[] words = text.split(" "); // split the input string by space
        for (String word : words) {
            wordMap.merge(word, 1, Integer::sum);
        }
        return wordMap;
    }
}
```

Or that way:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "Hello world Hello all";
        Map<String, Integer> wordMap = countWords(input);
        System.out.println(wordMap); // {all=1, world=1, Hello=2}
    }

    private static Map<String, Integer> countWords(final String text) {
        return Arrays.stream(text.split(" "))
            .collect(groupingBy(identity(), summingInt(x -> 1)));
    }
}
```

Comment: public Map<String, Integer> returnWordMap(String words){
 this is what I am trying to do

Comment: Then you can use `summingInt(s -> 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another way. Use [Map.merge](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)).

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
String s = "one three    five four   four"
        + "            two three five     four  four"
        + "   five five  three    two five";
```

`\\s+` - splits on one or more white space characters

```
for (String word : s.split("\\s+")) {
    map.merge(word, 1, Integer::sum);
}

map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
four=4
one=1
two=2
five=5
three=3
```